# Setting icons when a tab is selected

Tags: java, array, android

I have this 2 arrays :

```
final int[] tabSelected = {
        R.drawable.iconWhite0,
        R.drawable.iconWhite1,
        R.drawable.iconWhite2,
        R.drawable.iconWhite3,
        R.drawable.iconWhite4};
final int[] tabsUnselected = {
        R.drawable.iconBlack0,
        R.drawable.iconBlack1,
        R.drawable.iconBlack2,
        R.drawable.iconBlack3,
        R.drawable.iconBlack4};
```

I just don't understand how I can simplify this, by making a for loop ..although I am sure it is very easy, I just don't see it.

```
  @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabSelected[0]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabsUnselected[1]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabsUnselected[2]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabsUnselected[3]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setIcon(tabsUnselected[4]);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabsUnselected[0]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabSelected[1]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabsUnselected[2]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabsUnselected[3]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setIcon(tabsUnselected[4]);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabsUnselected[0]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabsUnselected[1]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabSelected[2]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabsUnselected[3]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setIcon(tabsUnselected[4]);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabsUnselected[0]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabsUnselected[1]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabsUnselected[2]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabSelected[3]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setIcon(tabsUnselected[4]);
                    break;


                default:
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabsUnselected[0]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabsUnselected[1]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabsUnselected[2]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabsUnselected[3]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setIcon(tabSelected[4]);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I've edited my post. It's Android SDK (Java)

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, **try to write a title that summarizes what your code does**, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.CodeReview.StackExchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You check whether the index of the tab equals the position. If this is the case, use the selected icon, otherwise use the unselected one:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  // maybe replace 5 with a constant declaration...
    if(i == position)
        tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(tabSelected[i]);
    else
        tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(tabsUnselected[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how i'd do it:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    int size = 4;
    position = Math.min(position, size);

    for(int i = 0; i <= size; i++){
        if(i == position){
            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(tabSelected[i]);
        }
        else {
            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(tabsUnselected[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Math.min(position,4) ensures this works even if position is bigger 4, as you handeled with the default case. Don't know what more to tell atm, feel free to ask!

I also added a size value which you can set static or dynamic for faster adaption in case size changes. This will keep the value in one place so its easier to maintain.

**Edit:**

Another approach:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    int size = 4;
    position = Math.min(position, size);

    for(int i = 0; i <= size; i++){
        tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(tabsUnselected[i]);
    }

    tabLayout.getTabAt(position).setIcon(tabSelected[position]);

}
```

even less complex but depending on how slow overwriting a Tab is it might really slow down the code, i doubt it will have significant impact.

**Edit2:**

Florian Salihovic kindly recommends: "`size` could be set to `TabLayout#getTabCount()`". You should have a look if this works for you.

Comment: I was about to post the second version as well. `size` could be set to `TabLayout#getTabCount()`.